spring boot variables pulling from some unknown source
I have recently taken over a source code for an application that is based in spring boot v. 2.5.10.  I have a .yml file that contains various configuration properties and settings. However, there are places in the code where annotations are being used for example
@Value("${my-setting.attribute}")
Example:
@Value("${my-setting.attribute}")
private String mySettingAttribute;

However, my-setting.attribute is nowhere to be found in my yml.  I have searched the server system environment variables and it's not there either. The only usage and reference to the variable is the file that is using it.
Where else would a property and it's value be hiding? I need to modify the value and adding it to the yml file does not affect the application.  This other source is taking precedence over the application.yml file.

Did you check if the properties have initial values in the source code?

@OussamaBASRY - I've searched the source code and any other .properties files I have access to. The only reference is the annotation.

I think you should check this annotation: @PropertySource. It defines the path to your configuration file.
Spring @value

I'm trying to understand the @PropertySource, is that going to tell me or reveal to me where the source of that property is?  Or is that where I force a property to pull from a specific source?

For example: @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") which means properties are stored in application.properties like "catalog.name=MovieCatalog" and value uses that one: @Value("${catalog.name}")

Okay, that makes sense.  But my issue is that I need to find where the original source of that value is being defined. Once I know that, then choosing to modify it with @PropertySource could be an option.
